# How to select an element inside an iframe?

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a wysiwig editor plugin.  I need the nugget of data at `iframe > html > body.class`.  I need to check for keyups in that element.  How does one address this problem if they do not have the ability to inject jquery in to the plugin?

Comment: ` I need to check for keyups in that element` lul

Comment: I think for security reasons this won't be possible. You're basically asking Javascript in one file to work on another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't manipulate or access iframe content if its content is from other site cos of cross browser issue.